# Spring Security OAuth - Provider Manager is Not Configured for Null Resource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, curl, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

Am trying to use Spring Secruity's OAuth API to obtain an access token from an externally published API.

This curl command works (and its contents are all that I need to obtain an access token):

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.app.com/v1/oauth/token \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=bcfrtew123&client_secret=Y67493012'
```

Am able to obtain an access token from the external service after running this curl command.

When using Spring Security OAuth API:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Setup my SpringMVC Controller's method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAccessToken", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(@RequestParam(value="client_id", required=true) String clientId, @RequestParam(value="client_secret", required=true) String clientSecret) throws Exception {
    String tokenUri = "https://api.app.com/v1/oauth/token";

    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUri);
    resourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    resourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
    resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));

    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

    oauth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);

    OAuth2AccessToken token = oauth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken();
    return token;
}
```

When I invoke the getAccessToken call from my local tomcat instance:

```
access_denied 
error_description=Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. 
The provider manager is not configured to support it.
```

Question(s):

1. What am I missing here? Is there some annotation required for this? Is there a property that is not set or is needed?

(Please notice that the content-type needs to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"...)

2. How can I mimic the working curl command using Spring Security OAuth API?
3. Could it be the default values that I have set in the RequestParameters?
4. If successful, how can I set it up so that access token is always preloaded before any request made?

Answer (score 11):

The real reason is, you are using `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` for a `"client_credentials"` access token request. We cannot interchange `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` and `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails`.

In `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails` you need to set `AccessTokenUri, ClientId, ClientSecret` and `grantType`.
In `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails`, you need to provide `Username and Password` along with `AccessTokenUri, ClientId, ClientSecret` and `GrantType`.

(Some authserver do accept `password` token request without `username and password`.. But I would say it is wrong)

Refer : [Securing an existing API with our own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767252/securing-an-existing-api-with-our-own-solution/51770779#51770779)

Answer (score 3):

This is what i use:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate oAuthRestTemplate() {
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setId("1");
    resourceDetails.setClientId(oAuth2ClientId);
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret(oAuth2ClientSecret);
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);

    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, oauth2ClientContext);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

The correct headers will be set bij the framework, but the username/password will be base64 encodes as Authorization header (basic authentication). This is the OAuth2 spec for a client_credentials grant.

Check if the api supports the spec:

```
curl -X POST \
'https://api.app.com/v1/oauth/token' \
-i -u 'client:secret' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

If you need to send the username & password as data instead of authorisation header, you can add `resourceDetails.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);` this should set de username & password as data

Comment: for me it was the `setId("1")`. It started working once I set it.

Comment: what is the significance of setId("1") ?

Comment: From the documentation: `Get a unique identifier for these protected resource details.`

Answer (score 0):

This could be oocured beacuse server doest not recognize the content type you posting to that specific url. 
In your CURL request try include the 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' for custom conrtroller using http headers.
[image: Http headers]

Also you have not set username and password for resourceDetails.
resourceDetails.setUserName("user");
resourceDetails.setUserName("password");

if those does not work try to extract the request that Encoded with application/x-www-form-urlencoded and pass it as a string via RestTemplate and you can get the token.

Let me know any if you need additional support.

Try the code below that is giving token as and string response.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response! How would I set that since this is OAuth2RestTemplate instead of RestTemplate? Also, if you look at the curl, there's no username / password set.

Comment: then option you have remaining is to include the content_type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: problem is what i have used is RestTemplate and you are using oauth2RestTemplate and you cant set any Http headers and in there unless you change it to RestTempalate. If you can fihure out a method to change that i can provide code.

Comment: The JavaDoc says that OAuth2RestTemplate is a subclass of RestTemplate:    http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html

Comment: I have added another new codes to my answer check that out.