# Oauth2 - How to automatically get access token

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, guzzle

I have a task which need to call an **external Oauth2 API** to get data.

The authentication steps of this API is:

1. Request an application authentication:

> https://api.apiname/v1/oauth?app_id= [value] & redirect_url = [value]
>   & response_type = [value] & scope = [value] & state = [value]

-> It will redirect to the login page of this API

2. Login then get the code
3. Use that code then request to get an access token:

> https://api.apiname/v1/token?grant_type=oauth_code&app_id=[value]&secret=[value]&code=[value]

4. Use received access token to call specific API to get data.

**So how can I get through step 1,2,3 automatically in my system because the client should not have to log in to API to get the code? Is there a way I can go through step 1 without showing login page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main purpose of Authorization code grant type in OAuth2 is to use a 3rd party login without having to save the user credentials in our app.

`"Is there a way I can go through step 1 without showing login page?"` : 
If you do this, this is in a way just client credential flow. I am not an expert, but I think this is technically possible using a chrome/firefox driver filling up the data for you using web scraping. But think twice before you use it since you are overriding the whole purpose of AuthCode grant type.

refer : [Securing an existing API with our own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767252/securing-an-existing-api-with-our-own-solution/51770779#51770779)